# Clear all cells in column who = ""?

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have a script that is plotting data points for me, and I'm running into an issue where there are several blank spots in the data.  Of of my columns is calculated, and I have a formula that sets it equal to "" if more than 0 cells that are used in the calculation are blank.  The plots that use the blank cells work fine to show gaps in the data, but Excel doesn't evaluate a cell that has a formula that results in "" as blank.

Therefore, I need to set up some code that can search the entire column of data and clear the formula out of the cells whose value equal "", thereby making them blank and displaying as gaps in the plot.

I know I can use the `Find` and `What` commands to find the **first** cell that is evaluated as "", but how can I use it to find **all** the cells in the column?

The row range for the data is always constant, between `4` and `243`, and the column number I am searching (within a loop) evaluates as `3*(iCounter - 1) + 2`, if that helps anyone.

(The range I am searching is equal to `Range(Cells(4, 3*(iCounter - 1) + 2), Cells(243, 3*(iCounter - 1) + 2))`

Comment: `how can I use it to find all the cells in the column` - use `FindNext`. See [.Find and .FindNext In Excel VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) for details

Comment: Okay, I will have to look at it Monday when I get back.  Something didn't come out right, but when does it ever the first time you code something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on any cell in the column you wish to cleanup and run this:

```
Sub ClearThem()
    Dim BigR As Range, r As Range
    Set BigR = Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each r In BigR
        If r.Value = "" Then r.Clear
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to modify a bit.  I had to use the code to select the cell (because this section is in a loop, and is all automatic), then I also had to change the range to be row 4 to 243, in the same column (where the data resides), because I have merged cells above and it throws an error.  Also, forgot your `End If` there.